Why the KeyListener doesn't work even when I request focus after fully rendering the JPanel?
I have written a game in Java. I have created a JFrame, added a JPanel to it then set the JPanel's focusable to true. The JPanel also implements KeyListener, and I also added the KeyListener to the JFrame, but somehow none of my methods for KeyListener work.
public class WindowGame {
    public static final int WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 720;
    
    private JFrame window;
    private Screen screen;
    private Level level;
    
    public WindowGame(){
        window = new JFrame("SpRED");
        window.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(false);
        
        screen = new InitialWindow(this);
        window.add(screen);
        window.addKeyListener(screen);
        
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WindowGame();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        window.remove(screen);
        window.removeKeyListener(screen);
        
        createLevel();
        screen = new Board(this, level);
        
        window.add(screen);
        screen.setFocusable(true);
        screen.requestFocus();
        window.addKeyListener(screen);
        window.revalidate();
    }
    
    public void winLevel() {
        window.remove(screen);
        window.removeKeyListener(screen);

        screen = new InitialWindow(this);
        
        window.add(screen);
        window.addKeyListener(screen);
        window.revalidate();
    }
    
    public void createLevel() {
        
    }
}

The screen implements KeyListener and its methods.
public abstract class Screen extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WindowGame window;
    private Timer timer;
    protected BufferedImage img;
    
    public Screen(WindowGame window){
        timer = new Timer(1000/10, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
        this.window = window;
    }
    
    protected void setImage(String path) {
        img = ImageLoader.loadImage(path);
    };

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Handle keyTyped event
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Handle keyPressed event
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // Handle keyReleased event
    }
}

Hope that I can find the solution for this problem.

One solution is to use Key Bindings instead of a KeyListener.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Only components that obtain the keyboard focus will fire events to key listeners. According to the code in your question, the JFrame, i.e. variable window in class WindowGame, will not since you are adding a JPanel to the JFrame. Hence the JPanel, i.e. variable screen in class WindowGame, is the component that will obtain keyboard focus (again, based entirely and solely on the code in your question) and therefore you need to add a KeyListener to it – and not to the JFrame.
The code in your question is not a complete, reproducible example since, among other things, it contains references to classes InitialWindow and Board whose code you did not post so I cannot tell you how to fix your code. Instead the below code merely demonstrates how to add a KeyListener to a JPanel.
Note that if you are adding other components to screen, then screen will never gain keyboard focus but rather the components added to screen will.
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class KeyLstnr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 450));
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        window.add(panel);
        panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Key pressed!");
            }
        });
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}


"Note that if you are adding other components to screen, then screen will never gain
keyboard focus but rather the components added to screen will."
Will it apply to JButton? My old game doesn't consist of any JButtons, and it works normally with the code I provided above.
